# Ediff: How to fill missing lines (gap) to achieve vertical alignment?

Tags: ediff

Oftentimes there are gaps in a side-by-side differential.  That is some lines were added, some were removed.  As I currently see it, `ediff` does not fill this gap by default.  Thus, vertical alignment between the two compared buffers is non-existent even if scrolled together.  Does anybody have a recipe to achieve such filling (potentially with newlines and/or filler characters)?

## Examples

---

### GUI

[image]

### TUI (`vimdiff`)

```
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod                                                    |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
  tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At                                                     |  tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
  vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,                                                   |  vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|  vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,                                                   
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit                                                      
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|  amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut                                                       
  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit                                                      |  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut                                                       |  amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
  labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam                                                    |  labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam
  et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata                                                       |  et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.                                                                                            |  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                                                                                                                                     |  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod                                                    |  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
  tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At                                                     |  tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
  vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,                                                   |  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit                                                      |  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut                                                       |  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam                                                    |  labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam
  et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata                                                       |  et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.                                                                                            |  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

**P.S.**  So, in fact, looking for `vimdiff`-like solution to `ediff`.

Comment: The question sure would be a lot more entertaining if there were a screenshot . . . ., and it might also motivate someone to try and find a solution -- especially if they could duplicate what you are seeing.

Comment: @lawlist, easy...

Comment: Sorry, but I for one do not understand the question. Wrt the screenshot, just what is it that you are asking? What "gaps" are you talking about? What do you want ediff to do differently?

Comment: @Drew, have you seen the `vimdiff` example?

Comment: This is a bit hard to follow.  I think you mean "in the vimdiff, the removed lines are filled in with the lines of dashes, but in ediff, it's just a blank line."  Is that correct?  If so, could you edit your post to clarify that that's what you're referring to?

Comment: Ediff shows neither the blank line or the dashes. The first screenshot shows how ediff would look if there were blank lines. The second screenshot shows how ediff would look if there were dashes. @AlexanderShukaev it might help to add a screenshot of how gui ediff looks that same file.

Comment: No. What `vimdiff` example? Did you show a `vimdiff` example? Did you link to a `vimdiff` example? You mean your "**TUI (vimdiff)**"? What does it have to do with your `ediff` screenshot (completely different text)? Sorry, but I have no idea what alternative behavior you are looking for, for `ediff`.

Comment: @Alexander Shukaev - that vimdiff example text is *terrible*. It's all lorem ipsum, so every line looks indistinguishable from any other at a glance (not helpful when discussing diffs), and then it's so wide that on this site it requires horizontal scrolling such that you *can't actually see both sides at the same time*. When you're asking for help, please make an effort to make the issue easy to comprehend.

Comment: I believe the key requirement here is that the bits of the text which are identical on both sides should (always) appear at the same vertical position on each side (which necessitates some kind of vertical padding on one side or the other, whenever there is a difference which has fewer lines on one of the sides).